# rpy2 for Holt Winters and UCM Model

Tags: python, statsmodels, rpy2

I am new to modelling and I am trying to design 2 models through python which are :

- Holt Winters
- Unobserved Component Model

And I saw that these models are available in R. Can i use rpy2 to call these functions from R into python ?

Thank you

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The rpy2 package allows you to pull in any r functions, bind to them in python, and interface with them in much the same way you would in R. Using a Pandas Dataframe with a timeseries index and a column called "consumptionPower". Of course your pandas Dataframe will be different.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

ts = robjects.r('ts')
c = robjects.r('c')
forecast=importr('forecast')
HoltWinters = robjects.r('HoltWinters')

training_pd = hourly['consumptionPower'][:"2017-06-01 00:00:00"]
trainingRTS=ts(training_pd.values, start=c(2015,6), frequency=8760)
hwPower = HoltWinters(trainingRTS, seasonal="additive")
```